# UCI C API - How to work with list options

Tags: c, openwrt

Using UCI we can retrieve entire lists with the following command:

```
$ uci get system.ntp.server
```

This would read the kind of configuration below:

```
config system
    option hostname 'OpenWrt'
    option timezone 'UTC'

config timeserver 'ntp'
    list server '0.openwrt.pool.ntp.org'
    list server '1.openwrt.pool.ntp.org'
    list server '2.openwrt.pool.ntp.org'
    list server '3.openwrt.pool.ntp.org'
    option enabled '1'
    option enable_server '0'
```

That returns all the ntp servers in one long string fine.

```
0.openwrt.pool.ntp.org 1.openwrt.pool.ntp.org 2.openwrt.pool.ntp.org 3.openwrt.pool.ntp.org
```

I wish to achieve the same (or equivalent) using the C api.

I put together the following code:

```
#include <uci.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    //char path[] = "system.ntp.enabled";
    char path[] = "system.ntp.server";
    char buffer[80];
    get_config_entry(path, &buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

}

int get_config_entry (char *path, char *buffer)
{
  struct uci_context *c;
  struct uci_ptr ptr;

  c = uci_alloc_context ();
  if (uci_lookup_ptr (c, &ptr, path, true) != UCI_OK)
    {
      uci_perror (c, "XXX");
      return 1;
    }

  strcpy(buffer, ptr.o->v.string);
  uci_free_context (c);
  return 0;
}
```

Running this just returns garbage in the output string.

How should I deal with list content using UCI C API?

Comment: You need to put a prototype for `get_config_entry` before `main` (or just move the whole function up before `main`). Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then the compiler would have helpfully pointed out your mistakes.

Comment: I removed the UCI tag, which is currently about the "universal chess interface", not about the "unified configuration interface".

Comment: I believe you should make the call like this:  get_config_entry(path,buffer);     Note "buffer" does not have an ampersand in front of it.

Comment: Paul & Tony. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a list element is requested it is stored in v.list not v.string.

I found the uci_show_value function in the uci cli code which helped a lot. I have managed to get the following code to work well with list options.

```
#include <uci.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *delimiter = " ";

static void uci_show_value(struct uci_option *o)
{
    struct uci_element *e;
    bool sep = false;

    switch(o->type) {
    case UCI_TYPE_STRING:
        printf("%s\n", o->v.string);
        break;
    case UCI_TYPE_LIST:
        uci_foreach_element(&o->v.list, e) {
            printf("%s%s", (sep ? delimiter : ""), e->name);
            sep = true;
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("<unknown>\n");
        break;
    }
}

int show_config_entry (char *path)
{
  struct uci_context *c;
  struct uci_ptr ptr;

  c = uci_alloc_context ();
  if (uci_lookup_ptr (c, &ptr, path, true) != UCI_OK)
    {
      uci_perror (c, "get_config_entry Error");
      return 1;
    }

  uci_show_value(ptr.o);
  uci_free_context (c);
  return 0;
}

void main()
{
    char path[] = "system.ntp.server";
    show_config_entry(path);

}
```